# Getting a reference to the current KeyboardFocusManager

Tags: java, swing, keyboardfocusmanager

Is there a way to get a reference to the current KeyboardFocusManager in a Swing application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked   [`KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager%28%29)

> Returns the current KeyboardFocusManager instance for the calling thread's context.